# Error running width.SJ() in R

Tags: r

Today, I am using the following code to check data's normality with nonparametric density estimation. However, I got the Error saying:

```
width.SJ(bc.mdat[, 2]) : 
  no solution in the specified range of bandwidths
```

So, I have no idea why this error will happen. Because I do this perfectly fine with another data. Thank you for your help

```
library(car)
library(MASS)
library(graphics)
Q=read.table(text='
 12.5  13.7
 14.5  16.5
 8.0   17.4
 9.0   11.0
 19.5  23.6
 8.0   13.2
 9.0   32.1
 7.0   12.3
 7.0   11.8
 9.0   24.4
 6.5   18.2
 10.5  22.0
 10.0  32.5
 4.5   18.7
 7.0   15.8
 8.5   15.6
 6.5   12.0
 8.0   12.8
 3.5   26.1
 8.0   14.5
 17.5  42.3
 10.5  17.5
 12.0  21.8
 6.0   10.4
 13.0  25.6
')
bc=powerTransform(as.matrix(Q)~1)
summary(bc)
bc.mdat<-bcPower(Q,bc$lambda)
f2=kde2d(bc.mdat[,1],bc.mdat[,2],h=c(width.SJ(bc.mdat[,1]),width.SJ(bc.mdat[,2])))
persp(f2,phi=30,theta=20,d=5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying some straightforward debugging shows the problem is with your second column, namely,

```
> width.SJ(bc.mdat[,2])
 Error in width.SJ(bc.mdat[, 2]) :
  no solution in the specified range of bandwidths
```

The problem is that for `mc.mdat[,2]`, which looks like this:

```
[1] 1.267853 1.300541 1.309183 1.223900 1.353462 1.260837 1.390182 1.247041 1.238636 1.357801 1.316270 1.344016 1.391514 1.320446 1.293266 1.291090 1.242067 1.254902 1.366288 1.278246 1.417488 1.310098
[23] 1.342756 1.211639 1.363888
```

the values that get computed in the `width.SJ` function (just type `width.SJ` and hit enter to see the function body), namely

```
> fSD(lower, cnt, alph2, c1, n, d)
[1] 0.003946731
> fSD(upper, cnt, alph2,  c1, n, d)
[1] 0.002883121
```

multiply to be more than `0`, and presumably this is some sort of singularity condition.

```
if (fSD(lower, cnt, alph2, c1, n, d) * fSD(upper, cnt, alph2,
    c1, n, d) > 0)
    stop("no solution in the specified range of bandwidths")
```

Here, `fSD` is the function given by `function (h, x, alph2, c1, n, d) (c1/SDh(x, alph2 * h^(5/7), n, d))^(1/5) - h`.

I am not sure what this could mean without digging deeper into the math, but hopefully this cursory debug session is enough to get you started. The solution will undoubtable lie with fixing your data set, or understanding why it is singular. I already tried removing up to four data points using `combn` but got the same problem, so it is a fundamental integrity problem.